# Sharing partials among layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, partials

I have a couple of layouts `main.html.haml` and `alternative.html.haml`, which share some elements. I would like to have a partial to share between them.

Using `render ='my_partial'` doesn't seem to work. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have created partial inside layouts folder then

try this

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/partial' %>
```

Hope this will help you